# Pygame getting coordinates without looping

Tags: python, loops, mouse, pygame

im making a game called StarDodger and im making a laser to shoot from the ship

the ships coords are the same as the mouse coords and i want the lser inamge to start at the ships coords then have the laser stay at the x coord and move vertical

the thing is when i try to get the coords they change every spilt second becuase the game is being updated in the loop

so i need a way to get the coords when i push the mouse button and laser = True and save those coords to a variable that doesnt change until i push it again

here is the method that shoots the laser:

```
def laser_shoot(self):
    self.laser_img = pygame.image.load('rec/game/laser.png')
    self.laser_img_r = self.laser_img.get_bounding_rect()
    self.mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y = self.mouse_pos
    self.laser_img_r.y+=15
    (self.laser_x, self.laser_y) = (self.mouse_x,self.laser_img_r.y)
    screen.blit(self.laser_img,(self.laser_x, self.laser_y))
```

the laser only shoots `if self.laser == True and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:`

what it does right now is get the x and y coords of the mouse then blit the laser at the mouses x coord and makes the y coord at 15 instead of looping and changing the lasers y pos by 15 each time the game loops

Answer (score 0):

- Does the laser x-coord stay constant even if the ship's x-coord moves after fire starts?
- It's best to load your sprites at start, it looks like you may be loading duplicate lasers.
- Grab the mouse coordinates on the mousedown event

I'm not clear on the movement without an image.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        # now use event.pos
```

It's common to 'spawn' an object when you fire bullets/lasers. On LMB (and fire is ok) then spawn `Laser(pos=event.pos)` . It will remember the start location, and will grow every `Laser.update()`, until it dies. Which if it's a sprite you just do `self.kill()`.

Comment: the x-coord will stay the same and the if statment works fine i just need a way to get the mouse pos once and not have it change until i click again

Comment: To do that, you grab it on the event, and save it to a variable.

Comment: im trying to but it loops the event so the variables keep changing i tried what you gave me but cant get it to work

Comment: On the event where I have a comment you can spawn a new class named `Laser` , which it remembers the coordinates. Each instance will remember it's own location no matter how many new events come in.

Comment: Interesting I don't really want to make a whole new class but that might be the best way I'll try it